# convert tabs to spaces

Tags: code-golf, string

Write the shortest possible code which converts tabs to spaces in the input. Tab size should be supplied as a parameter or be hardcoded in the code **in a single place**.

Spaces on output should point to the right column, e.g. (`\t` represents a tab character):

```
a\tb
aa\tb
aaa\tb
aaaa\tb
```

should become (for tab size 4):

```
a   b
aa  b
aaa b
aaaa    b
```

Of course there can be more than one tab in a line.

Line separator and tab character should match the system defaults (e.g. ASCII 10 and 9 on Unix).

Comment: I think this would be too trivial in any language with RegExp support.
And there is also a coreutils utility `expand` which does just this.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57462/47066)

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/91860/47066)

Comment: I did not notice it was already there, is there a way to delete a question?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18960/47066)

Comment: In the future, please post your challenges [in the Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) and let it sit there for a couple of days.

Comment: Hi mik, You can use the delete button at the bottom-left of the question, next to edit :)

Comment: The [linked dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57462/47066) was not a dupe at all in my opinion as it only requires to replace some tabs with a constant amount of spaces, whereas here all tabs need to be converted to a varying amount of spaces based on there position.

Comment: As for the other proposed dupe ([Expand tabs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18960/expand-tabs-implement-expand1)), that's closer but also more involved and requires parsing of a *tabstop specification string*, so I wouldn't necessarily consider it a dupe either.

Comment: Should we assume the non-whitespace parts of the input will all be ASCII range characters, or any Unicode character? Makes a difference for iteration in some languages, among other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 36 bytes

```perl
1while s/	/$"x($^I-length($`)%$^I)/e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@wPCMzJ1WhWJ9TX0WpQkMlzlM3JzUvvSRDQyVBUxXI1dRP/f8/kTOJKxFCQEkwxQkRhooDqX/5BSWZ@XnF/3UL/utmmgAA)

Tab length is controlled with `-i` command-line parameter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 106 bytes

```python
def f(s,w):
 for l in s.split('\n'):
  L=''
  for x in l.split('\t'):L+=' '*(w-(len(L)%w))+x
  print L[w:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcsxDsIwDIXhnVN4QbZpYUBMlXqD3KBhKKIRkSI3aiylnD4kA53@J/lz/OpnlXsp78WBo9RnHk7g1g0CeIF0SzF4JbSC7QBmRKxpYG8gHEArMN2IgBfKVwqLkOFzZu72@hA3LwpmysOzOMLZ6svK/M/RNrB/cPkB)

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 16 bytes

```
:se ts=4 et
:ret
```

Comment: you can combine setting the two options on a single line and shorten `:set` to `:se`

Comment: I would expect the settings unchanged at the end.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 24 bytes

```
VQ=+k:NJ"   "d=.[kd|nNJ4)k
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQ%3D%2Bk%3ANJ%22%09%22d%3D.%5Bkd%7CnNJ4%29k&input=%22aa%5Ctbbbb%5Ctccc%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
VQ=+k:NJ"   "d=.[kd|nNJ4)k
VQ                      )    For each character in the input...
  =+k:NJ"   "d               ... add the character with tab replaced by space
                             to k (initially empty)...
              =.[kd          ... then pad k with spaces...
                   |nNJ4     ... to the nearest multiple of 4 if the character
                             is a tab and 1 otherwise.
                         k   Output k.
```

Alternatively, if we want to input the tab length, we can do so with `Vz=+k:NJ" "d=.[kd|nNJQ)k`.
[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Vz%3D%2Bk%3ANJ%22%09%22d%3D.%5Bkd%7CnNJQ%29k&input=4%0Aaa%09bbbb%09ccc&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 11, 134 bytes

```java
n->s->{for(var l:s.split("\n")){var t="";for(var p:l.split("\t"))t+=" ".repeat(n-t.length()%n)+p;System.out.println(t.substring(n));}}
```

This time an answer for which I correctly read the challenge.. >.>

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bVCxbsIwEN35ilOkSrZIrA6dCGSpVKlDJ0bCYIKBUOdi2WcqhPLt6VEMLJ3une/53nt31CddHLffY2N1CPClW7xMAAJpahs48lRFaq3aRWyo7VF9JDD/RDJ74/P/SO89htgZP1@Sb3FfVbCDBYxYVKGoLrvei5P2YGdBBWdbElmNmZSX6yMtsqy8M9zMPhjEDJouvHFGcw9ZjgUpa3BPByFfUE5duTwHMp3qIynHwmRRkApxE/5sCJSyHIaxnHBCFzeWE6agp77dQsfhxc3xag1aXg8BsFPaOXsWb1LppjGOtXVNmxr1vTxqAjU95k8Go0yWvHGYPO97E4OUKXVsNgc2D7rrI1Ky4Q1Fj4DmJ/0SV9gctF/deGupeI/VjeFjvWY5r0l6w/gL).
NOTE: Because Java 11 isn't on TIO yet, the `String.repeat(int)` has been emulated with `repeat(String,int)` for the same byte-count.

**Explanation:**

```java
n->s->{                      // Method with int & String parameters and String return-type
  for(var l:s.split("\n")){  //  Split the input by newlines, and loop over the lines:
    var t="";                //   Temp-String, starting empty
    for(var p:l.split("\t")) //   Split the line by tabs, and loop over the parts
      t+=" ".repeat(n-t.length()%n)
                             //    Append `n - length_of_t modulo-n` amount of spaces,
         +p;                 //    as well as part `p` to the temp-String
      System.out.println(    //    Print with trailing new-line:
        t                    //     The temp-String `t`
         .substring(n));}}   //      after we've removed the trailing spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 118

An anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes an input string from range `[A1]` and an input tab length from range `[B1]`, and outputs to the console.

```vb
For Each l In Split([A1],vbLf):Do:i=InStr(1,l,"\t"):l=Replace(l,"\t",Space([B1]-(i-1)Mod[B1]),,1):Loop While i:?l:Next
```

#### Ungolfed

```vb
Public Sub tabReplace(ByRef value As String, Optional tabLen As Integer = 4)
    Dim line, index As Integer
    For Each line In Split(value, vbLf)
        Do
            Let index = InStr(1, line, "\t")
            Let line = Replace(line, "\t", Space(tabLen - (index - 1) Mod tabLen), , 1)
        Loop While index
        Debug.Print line
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 103 bytes

```python
def F(I,c):
 while'\t'in I:t=I.find('\t');I=I.replace('\t',' '*(c-(t+~I[:t].rfind('\n'))%c),1)
 print I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCsIwEEX3OcVQkCQaC4qrittCzmBctGmKgTgtdUTcePWYRnGhm/n8x38zPug84DbGzvVQC62srBjczz44boh7BF3RQZe9x07MRO51qpMbQ2NdJooDXwq7FrR66mNFp3L6rJFLubBSbSSDcfJIoGMtiqJoDLUsnRzv8o0500TBTjKWLZYcHICa9vqP04/LLZA3FDw6g78kG/EF)

I wanted to evade `split` and use some `replace` (tbh I've started with regex).

I replace each `\t` with `c-(t+~I[:t].rfind('\n'))%c` number of spaces. Where `t` - index of current `\t` and `t+~I[:t].rfind('\n')` is distance to the closest `\n` (or start of string) on left.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
StringReplace[#,"	"->Array[" "&,4]<>""]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P7ikKDMvPSi1ICcxOTVaWUeJU0nXzrGoKLEyWklBSU3HJNbGTkkpVu1/AFBdSXSag1IiZxJXIoSAkkBKKfY/AA)

Sadly, Mathematica doesn't let you multiply a string by a number to duplicate it, otherwise it would be shorter than Perl.

---

Explanation:

`StringReplace[#,` Replace all instances of

`"  "` a tab character

`->Array[" "` with an array of spaces

`,4]` four long

`<>""]&` joined to the empty string.

Comment: the answer should preserve columns, and not always add 4 spaces

Comment: I don't understand, sorry.

Comment: a tab after a single another character at the beginning of the line should be converted to 3 spaces, not 4; look at the example in the question